# C - not reaching proper end with fork(), pipe(), select(), execl(), and write()

Tags: c, multithreading, select, fork, pipe

I am using forks and pipes to find the amount of 1s and 0s in a string inside of a file. However, I am never reaching the proper end to my program that tallys up the ones and zeroes. It's a pretty small amount of code so here is the whole program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/time.h>

int main (int argc, char** argv)
{
        int leftR, rightR;
        char *string;
        long size;
        int recursion = 0;
        if (argc == 3)
        {
                string = argv[1];
                size = strlen(string);
                printf("the string is %s\n", string);
                if (size <= 2)
                {

                        int bitCounter[2];
                        bitCounter[0] = 0;
                        bitCounter[1] = 0;
                        int i;
                        for (i=0; i < size; i++)
                        {
                                if (string[i]=='0')
                                {
                                        bitCounter[0]++;
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                        bitCounter[1]++;
                                }
                        }
                        write(STDOUT_FILENO, &bitCounter, sizeof(int)*2);
                        printf("read bits, sending back %d ones and %d zeroes\n", bitCounter[1], bitCounter[0]);
                        return 0;
                }
                else
                {
                        recursion = 1;
                }
        }
        if (argc == 2 || recursion)
        {
                char *data;
                if (!recursion)
                {
                        FILE* filePointer;
                        if ((filePointer = fopen(argv[1], "r")) == NULL)
                        {
                                perror("file didn't work");
                        }
                        fseek(filePointer, 0, SEEK_END);
                        size = ftell(filePointer);
                        fseek(filePointer, 0, SEEK_SET);
                    data = malloc(size+1);
                        fread(data, size, 1, filePointer);
                        fclose(filePointer);
                }
                else
                {
                        data = malloc(size+1);
                        data = string;
                }

                char *right;
                char *left = malloc((size/2)+1);
                if (size%2 == 0)
                {
                        right = malloc(size/2 + 1);
                }
                else
                {
                        right = malloc(size/2 + 2);
                }

                memcpy(left, data, size/2);

                if (size%2 == 0)
                {
                        memcpy(right, (size/2) + data, size/2);
                }
                else
                {
                        memcpy(right, (size/2) + data, (size/2) + 1);
                }

                int pidLeft, pidRight;
                int leftPipe[2];
                int rightPipe[2];

                pipe(leftPipe);
                pipe(rightPipe);

                fd_set readF;

                FD_ZERO(&readF);
                FD_SET(leftPipe[0], &readF);
                FD_SET(rightPipe[0], &readF);

                pidLeft = fork();
                if (pidLeft > 0)
                {
                        pidRight = fork();
                        if (pidRight > 0)
                        {
                                struct timeval timer;
                                timer.tv_sec = 3;
                                timer.tv_usec = 0;

                                close(rightPipe[1]);
                                close(leftPipe[1]);
                                dup2(leftPipe[0], STDOUT_FILENO);
                                dup2(rightPipe[0], STDOUT_FILENO);

                                select(2, &readF, NULL, NULL, &timer);
                                read(leftPipe[0], &leftR, sizeof(int)*2);
                                read(rightPipe[0], &rightR, sizeof(int)*2);
                                printf("going back to parent.\n");
                        }
                        else if (pidRight == 0)
                        {
                                close(rightPipe[0]);
                                execl("my_program", "my_program", right, "y",  NULL);
                                printf("recursion start\n");
                                exit(1);
                        }
                }
                else if (pidLeft == 0)
                {
                        close(leftPipe[0]);
                        execl("my_program", "my_program", left, "y", NULL);
                        printf("start recursion LEFT\n");
                        exit(1);
                }
                else
                {
                        fprintf(stderr, "something went wrong! No fork!\n");
                }
        }
        else
        {
                fprintf(stderr, "Please input file name properly\n");
                exit(1);
        }
    int zeroes = leftR + rightR;
    int* numOnes[2];
    numOnes[0] = &leftR + sizeof(int);
    numOnes[1] = &rightR + sizeof(int);
    int ones = (int) *numOnes[0] + (int) *numOnes[1];
    printf("0's: %d\n1's: %d\n", zeroes, ones);
    return 0;

}
```

However, the output never reaches my desired end that adds everything up:

```
the string is 01010▒z
the string is 010
the string is 0
read bits, sending back 0 ones and 1 zeroes
the string is 10▒z
the string is 10
read bits, sending back 1 ones and 1 zeroes
the string is ▒z
read bits, sending back 2 ones and 0 zeroes
the string is 10
read bits, sending back 1 ones and 1 zeroes
the string is 10100
z
the string is 101
the string is 1
read bits, sending back 1 ones and 0 zeroes
the string is 01
read bits, sending back 1 ones and 1 zeroes
the string is 00
z
the string is 00
read bits, sending back 0 ones and 2 zeroes
the string is
z
read bits, sending back 2 ones and 0 zeroes
(140) Admin $
```

A couple quick points to understand the code a little easier:

- argc is only 3 when it is being executed within a child
- children will only read the string if it is less than or equal to 2, otherwise recursively cut the string in half again (and make more children)
- parents make both a left and right child, both taking half of the string to work on

I guess a couple easy questions to start off would be:

- Am I using select() and execl() properly?
- Am I using read() and write() properly?
- Is there an exit in the main processes I am missing?
- Are both children working and using the pipe correctly?
- (less important) is the strange character in the strings messing up my count? Is that a null terminator somehow inside my string?

Comment: Please post code that compiles without errors: `int zeroes = *leftR + *rightR;` generates errors because neither `leftR` nor `rightR` is a pointer.  The next line also gets similar complaints.

Comment: Fixed, sorry about that.

Comment: 'Fixed' is not, perhaps, the term I'd use.  This code: `int rights = (int) &rightR;
    int lefts = (int) &leftR;
    int zeroes = lefts + rights;
    int ones = (int)(&leftR + sizeof(int)) + (int)(&rightR + sizeof(int));` is extraordinary — and extremely unlikely to be correct.  Adding two addresses together yields garbage, not an answer.  I'm not sure what you think the `(&leftR + sizeof(int))` is going to yield, but it isn't 'defined behaviour'.

Comment: Also, given that `leftR` and `rightR` are each single integers, the code `read(leftPipe[0], &leftR, sizeof(int)*2);
read(rightPipe[0], &rightR, sizeof(int)*2);` reading two `int` values into each of the single integers is guaranteed to be undefined behaviour.

Comment: Yes, that is most definitely the case. The main problem is my program doesn't even reach this last area for me to even debug it properly. Essentially that `(&leftR + sizeof(int))` is supposed to take the next element out of the array `bitCounter` that was passed from the left child.

Anyway, I made changes to hopefully avoid undefined benhaviour.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one of the tougher nuts to crack.  The code is doing an obscure job and is written rather obscurely.  As far as I can tell, it is supposed to be called `my_program`, and is due to be invoked with a file name as a single argument.  The process will then open the file, read its content into two arrays (`left` and `right`), without bothering to ensure that they are strings (no null termination).  The process then forks twice.  One then execs itself with the `left` (non-)string as an argument and the information that it is `left`, and one execs itself with the `right` (non-)string as an argument and the information that it is right.  The parent process messes around with `select()` for no very good reason, and without checking the return value.  It then calls read to get information on the two pipes.  These reads would block until there's data ready, so the `select()` really doesn't help at all. (I'm still trying to work out where the recursion bit fits in.)  Also, most of the system calls are not error checked.

However, given that outline operation (read file, split, children exec and do half each and report back), I would be writing something like this:

```
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdarg.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>

static void err_exit(char const *fmt, ...);

int main(int argc, char * *argv)
{
    int l_data[2]  = { -1, -1 };
    int r_data[2] = { -1, -1 };
    char *string;
    size_t size;
    char *arg0 = argv[0];

    if (argc != 2 && argc != 3)
        err_exit("Usage: %s file\n", argv[0]);

    if (argc == 3)
    {
        /* Child process */
        string = argv[1];
        size = strlen(string);
        fprintf(stderr, "%d: the string is %s\n", (int)getpid(), string);
        if (size <= 2)
        {
            int bitCounter[2];
            bitCounter[0] = 0;
            bitCounter[1] = 0;
            for (size_t i = 0; i < size; i++)
            {
                if (string[i] == '0')
                    bitCounter[0]++;
                else if (string[i] == '1')
                    bitCounter[1]++;
            }
            if (write(STDOUT_FILENO, bitCounter, sizeof(int)*2) != sizeof(int)*2)
                err_exit("%d: failed to write on standard output\n",
                        (int)getpid());
            fprintf(stderr, "%d: read bits, sending back %d ones and %d zeroes\n",
                   (int)getpid(), bitCounter[1], bitCounter[0]);
            exit(0);
        }
        fprintf(stderr, "%d: doing recursion - string too big (%zu)\n",
                (int)getpid(), size);
    }

    char *data = string;
    if (argc == 2)
    {
        FILE *filePointer;
        if ((filePointer = fopen(argv[1], "r")) == NULL)
        {
            perror("file didn't work");
            exit(1);
        }
        fseek(filePointer, 0, SEEK_END);
        size = ftell(filePointer);
        fseek(filePointer, 0, SEEK_SET);
        data = malloc(size+1);
        fread(data, size, 1, filePointer);
        data[size] = '\0';
        if (data[size-1] == '\n')
            data[--size] = '\0';
        fclose(filePointer);
        fprintf(stderr, "%d: data <<%s>>\n", (int)getpid(), data);
    }

    size_t l_size = size/2;
    size_t r_size = size - l_size;
    char *left = malloc(l_size+1);
    char *right = malloc(r_size+1);

    memcpy(left, data, l_size);
    left[l_size] = '\0';
    memcpy(right, data + l_size, r_size);
    right[r_size] = '\0';

    int l_pid, r_pid;
    int l_pipe[2] = { -1, -1 };
    int r_pipe[2] = { -1, -1 };

    if (pipe(l_pipe) != 0 || pipe(r_pipe) != 0)
        err_exit("%d: Failed to create pipes\n", (int)getpid());

    fprintf(stderr, "%d: forking (l_size = %zu, r_size = %zu)\n",
            (int)getpid(), l_size, r_size);
    l_pid = fork();
    if (l_pid < 0)
        err_exit("%d: Failed to fork() left child\n", (int)getpid());
    else if (l_pid == 0)
    {
        dup2(l_pipe[1], STDOUT_FILENO);
        close(l_pipe[0]);
        close(l_pipe[1]);
        close(r_pipe[0]);
        close(r_pipe[1]);
        fprintf(stderr, "%d: left execing with string <<%s>>\n", (int)getpid(), left);
        execl(arg0, arg0, left, "y", NULL);
        err_exit("%d: failed to start recursion LEFT\n", (int)getpid());
    }
    else if ((r_pid = fork()) < 0)
        err_exit("%d: Failed to fork() right child\n", (int)getpid());
    else if (r_pid == 0)
    {
        dup2(r_pipe[1], STDOUT_FILENO);
        close(l_pipe[0]);
        close(l_pipe[1]);
        close(r_pipe[0]);
        close(r_pipe[1]);
        fprintf(stderr, "%d: right execing with string <<%s>>\n", (int)getpid(), right);
        execl(arg0, arg0, right, "y",  NULL);
        err_exit("%d: failed to start recursion RIGHT\n", (int)getpid());
    }
    else
    {
        /* Parent process */
        int nbytes;
        close(r_pipe[1]);
        close(l_pipe[1]);
        if ((nbytes = read(l_pipe[0], l_data, sizeof(int)*2)) != sizeof(int)*2)
            err_exit("%d: Read left pipe failed (%d)\n", (int)getpid(), nbytes);
        if ((nbytes = read(r_pipe[0], r_data, sizeof(int)*2)) != sizeof(int)*2)
            err_exit("%d: Read right pipe failed (%d)\n", (int)getpid(), nbytes);
        close(l_pipe[0]);
        close(r_pipe[0]);
    }

    int zeroes = l_data[0] + r_data[0];
    int ones   = l_data[1] + r_data[1];
    if (argc == 3)
    {
        int data[2] = { zeroes, ones };
        if (write(STDOUT_FILENO, data, sizeof(data)) != sizeof(data))
            err_exit("%d: failed to read binary data from stdin\n", (int)getpid());
        fprintf(stderr, "%d: binary write to stdout OK\n", (int)getpid());
    }

    fprintf(stderr, "%d: 0's = %d, 1's = %d\n", (int)getpid(), zeroes, ones);
    return 0;
}

static void err_exit(char const *fmt, ...)
{
    int errnum = errno;
    va_list args;
    va_start(args, fmt);
    vfprintf(stderr, fmt, args);
    va_end(args);
    if (errnum != 0)
        fprintf(stderr, "%d: %s\n", errnum, strerror(errnum));
    exit(1);
}
```

Given an input file:

```
0101010111111
```

the output is:

```
11070: data <<0101010111111>>
11070: forking (l_size = 6, r_size = 7)
11073: right execing with string <<0111111>>
11072: left execing with string <<010101>>
11072: the string is 010101
11072: doing recursion - string too big (6)
11072: forking (l_size = 3, r_size = 3)
11073: the string is 0111111
11073: doing recursion - string too big (7)
11073: forking (l_size = 3, r_size = 4)
11074: left execing with string <<010>>
11075: right execing with string <<101>>
11076: left execing with string <<011>>
11077: right execing with string <<1111>>
11074: the string is 010
11074: doing recursion - string too big (3)
11074: forking (l_size = 1, r_size = 2)
11078: left execing with string <<0>>
11076: the string is 011
11076: doing recursion - string too big (3)
11076: forking (l_size = 1, r_size = 2)
11079: right execing with string <<10>>
11075: the string is 101
11075: doing recursion - string too big (3)
11075: forking (l_size = 1, r_size = 2)
11080: left execing with string <<0>>
11077: the string is 1111
11077: doing recursion - string too big (4)
11077: forking (l_size = 2, r_size = 2)
11082: right execing with string <<11>>
11081: left execing with string <<1>>
11083: right execing with string <<01>>
11084: left execing with string <<11>>
11085: right execing with string <<11>>
11079: the string is 10
11078: the string is 0
11079: read bits, sending back 1 ones and 1 zeroes
11078: read bits, sending back 0 ones and 1 zeroes
11074: binary write to stdout OK
11074: 0's = 2, 1's = 1
11082: the string is 11
11082: read bits, sending back 2 ones and 0 zeroes
11080: the string is 0
11080: read bits, sending back 0 ones and 1 zeroes
11076: binary write to stdout OK
11076: 0's = 1, 1's = 2
11081: the string is 1
11081: read bits, sending back 1 ones and 0 zeroes
11084: the string is 11
11084: read bits, sending back 2 ones and 0 zeroes
11083: the string is 01
11083: read bits, sending back 1 ones and 1 zeroes
11075: binary write to stdout OK
11075: 0's = 1, 1's = 2
11072: binary write to stdout OK
11072: 0's = 3, 1's = 3
11085: the string is 11
11085: read bits, sending back 2 ones and 0 zeroes
11077: binary write to stdout OK
11077: 0's = 0, 1's = 4
11073: binary write to stdout OK
11073: 0's = 1, 1's = 6
11070: 0's = 4, 1's = 9
```

Comment: Great job! Works perfect